# A second polylogarithm ladder for the tribonacci and n-nacci constants

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, polylogarithms

In "[*A seventeenth-order polylogarithm ladder*](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/ladder.pdf)", on page 6 (eq 25), Bailey et al give a dilogarithmic ladder that begins with,

$$0 = \operatorname{Li_2(\alpha_1^{-630})}-2\operatorname{Li_2(\alpha_1^{-315})}-3\operatorname{Li_2(\alpha_1^{-210})}\dots\tag{1}$$

where $\alpha_1 = 1.176280\dots$ is the larger real root of [*Lehmer's polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_number). They remark that, "...whose index, $k = 630$, exceeds anything found previously..." Perhaps we can make the index arbitrary.

Given the root $1<x<2$ of,

$$x^n(2-x) = 1\tag{2}$$

I used *Mathematica*'s Integer Relations command to find the proposed relation,

$$0 = \operatorname{Li_2(1/x^{2n+2})}-4\operatorname{Li_2(1/x^{n+1})}+4\operatorname{Li_2(1/x^n)}-\operatorname{Li_2(1/x^{n-1})}\tag{3}$$

for any integer $n>0$. Of course, the index is $k=2n+2$ for arbitrary $n$. For $n = 2$, the root $x$ is the *golden ratio*, $n = 3$ it is the *tribonacci constant*, and so on.

*Question*: Given the root $x$ of $(2)$, does the ladder $(3)$ hold true for all integer $n>0$?

P.S. The first polylogarithm ladder for the n-nacci constants is discussed in this MSE [*post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481682/polylogarithm-ladders-for-the-tribonacci-and-n-nacci-constants).